# PHP Shell_exec() Unexpected output?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am working on some scripts that try to get information from The computers at my University.

When i run the code:

```
$you = shell_exec('whoami');  
echo $you;
```

the output returned is `Apache` but thats not the output I was expecting. While trying to figure this out, I tried running the code:

```
$host = shell_exec('hostname');  
echo $host;
```

And from that I got, `ad7ad7.securesites.net` which, again, is not the hostname I wanted. This seems to be a Virtual Private Server.

So my main question is there away to get around this Private Server? because I want to get the information of the computer and it seems to be picking up this server. I am sure it is some sercurity thing, but I was just wondering if there was away around it (or maybe I am doing something wrong, I really dont know).

I know there are functions to get the host name already. But I was using shell_exec for other function and I believe this server is in the way of what I want to achieve.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you open the page / script from your browser, it is actually the web-server that is running the php script (apache, www, etc.). When you run your php script directly from the command line, you will probably see the results you were expecting as then you / your user is executing the php.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to run in the browser like the command line?

Comment: Not really, a web-server is (and should be) really *unrelated* (for lack of a better word) to the operating system it is running on. And even your command line environment could be a virtual system itself.

Comment: Yeah, these are completely unrelated worlds. The server doesn't usually know who you are. Perhaps you should elaborate on what you want to do, in what kind of environment? There may be an alternative way.

Comment: Well what i am trying to do, is make a computer availability map for the computer labs at my university. However i dont want to have to reimage the computers.

Comment: You can add a script on the server to run as sudo i.e hostname-check.sh  then run $data = shell_exec('sudo /opt/hostname-check.sh');  
echo $data;    - then you can allow www-data to run that script by adding it to the end of the sudoers file:  www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /opt/hostname-check.sh     but remember that you shouldnt let www-data run priv commands.